# What is the difference between Azure SQL VM and Azure VM where we install SQL Server manually

Tags: azure-vm

- **Question 1** - what is the difference if i create a VM and install SQL Server on it by myself vs Azure SQL VM.
  With respect to licensing, I will anyway use the hybrid licensing to make use of on-prem license.
  Is there any significant different apart from that, MS installs the SQL server on C: but I can install it else where.
  Currently when I check in portal, I see the server listed in Virtual machine and in SQL Virtual machine for both SQL VM and VM where SQL Server is installed manually.
  When i browse over the SQL Virtual Machine section i do not see certain options enabled like Security, Patching, backups, Additional features etc., for the version VM where SQL Server is installed manually
- **Question 2** - SQL Server with Azure DB PaaS vs Managed SQL Server (comes on VM)
  Here my understanding is SQL Server is completely managed by MS and we need not worry about anything. Just create SQL Server, add Azure DB paas to use them. Or am i missing something?

Thanks you!!!

Comment: What are you actually asking? You seem to already know what the differences are, so what's the real question here? [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-on-azure-vm-iaas-what-is-overview) is pretty comprehensive so what specifically do you need to know?

Comment: Would like to understand when we choose what. What distinction does each have over the other.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627).